# How to set UIButton's highlighted property to NO?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uibutton

While i am touching a `UIButton` how can I make it not highlighted. I don't want to just completely shun the highlighted feature however. I just want to make the highlighted stop when I begin to drag. I have tried this though

```
-(IBAction)stopHighlighting:(UIButton *)sender// i hooked this up to IB for touchDragInside
{

sender.highlighted=NO;
//this doesnt work at all
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the system will override your logic.  It calls the target method *before* darkening the image for highlight so basically you will set it to `NO` and then it will set it back to `YES` and you will see nothing.  You have two options:

1) Use dispatch_async to delay your call to highlight until after the system has set it.

2) Disable the runtime highlighting and switch your images manually.